# Setting MySQL Query As Multiple Variables In Shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm sorry if this question is overly succinct, but I am attempting to run a MySQL query via a Shell script, and am hoping to query several different "columns" in my result.  This is all working well, but where I am struggling, is to figure out how I could set each of these "columns" as unique variables in my Shell script.  Here is what I have;

```
#!/bin/sh

results=$(mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=root Database --skip-column-names -e 'Select cost1, cost2, cost3 from Customers';)

someMath () {
total=$1+$2+$3
echo $total
}

for cost in $results;
do
someMath $cost1 $cost2 $cost3
done

exit 0
```

Where I struggle is to figure out how I could feasibly set all of the "cost1" in the query results to be $cost1, all of the "cost2" in the query to be $cost2, and all of the "cost3" in the query to be $cost3.  My plan is to feed these variables to another function to perform other tasks.

I know this may be rudimentary, but despite my searching, I just can't figure this out!  Thank you!

Comment: can you explain what you are doing with that row data, those rows, let's say you get 3 rows back, later in your script ? you are doing more than echo right ?

Comment: Hi @DrewPierce - Yes, I will be doing more than echo.  I will be feeding the three variables, in this example, to another shell script, which will do some calculations with the datasets.  These variables in the example are only placeholders; my real variables deal with numbers and mathematics.

Comment: Alan i can help you with that but might not be in the exact form you want. Can you provide The Stack with more info in the form of pseudo code high level

Comment: Hi @DrewPierce - I've updated my question with some changed code that hopefully further explains a general idea of what I'm after!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need each row, each column and pass them some other functions separately. Here's an example i wrote:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 someListReceiver () {
    ## you know how many values you pass so you can use $1 $2...
    ## simple math with bc
    echo "$1+$2+$3" | bc
 }

 someArrayReceiver () {
    ## Looping a received array if you don't know how many columns you'll get
    declare -a arrayArguments=("${!1}")

    c=0
    for i in  "${arrayArguments[@]}"
    do
        let c+=$i
    done
    echo $c
 }

 while read line
 do
     ## IFS is your seperator, you can choose which it is, or you can use default space and us it with CONCAT_WS
     IFS=$';'
     for column in $line
     do
         ## assign rows each value to an array
         columnsAr+=($column)

         ## you can check every column with this
         ## echo "$column of $line"
     done

     ## pass your row list to some function 
     someListReceiver ${columnsAr[@]}

     ## or pass your array to function
     someArrayReceiver columnsAr[@]

     ## unset array to refill
     unset columnsAr

 done < <(mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=123 test --skip-column-names -e "SELECT CONCAT_WS(';', cost1, cost2, cost3) FROM customers;")
```

You can change passing array data however you like.

Comment: I see what you're doing here!  Thanks very much, @mim., this is so helpful!